# How to Decode nested JSON in Swift?

Tags: swift

I am trying to decode a nested JSON. Can someone please help me in decoding the below json format in Swift?

```
let jsonString = """
{
    "@odata.context": "https://www.Google.com",
    "value": [{
        "message": {
            "url": "https://www.example.com",
            "path": "cdrive/hello"
        }
    }]
}
"""
```

I have tried to decode it like below:

==========================

```
struct Response: Codable {
    let value: [Value]
}

struct Value: Codable {
    let message: Message
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case message
    }
}

struct Message: Codable {
    let url: String
    let path: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case url = "url"
        case path = "path"
    }
}

func testJSON() {
 
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let data = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!
    let blogPosts: [Response] = try! decoder.decode([Response].self, from: data)
    print(blogPosts.count) 
    // Trying to parse Url from tha above jso object 
 
 }
```

Comment: The json isn't a [Response], it's just a single Response object, so try! decoder.decode(Response.self, from: data) or make your json an array with  [ ]

Comment: Your json contains a single top item but you are decoding an array

Comment: call `testJSON()` and read the error in the console. It tells you exactly what's wrong

Comment: Yes, it worked fine when I used a single Response object. 

I have one followup question here: 
In most of the cases, json format are exactly same. However, sometime server is responding with "message1" or "message2" or "message3" instead of "message" in the json. In this case, how to update my code so it will be able to parse/decode the json format.

Comment: Replace definition of `value` with `let value = [[String: Message]]`, that is remove the type `Value` and use a dictionary in its place.

Answer (score -2):

Try with this (Replace Response array with Response only)

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
 let data = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)!
 let blogPosts: Response = try! decoder.decode(Response.self, from: data)
 print(blogPosts)
```

Comment: Yes, it worked fine when I used a single Response object. 

I have one followup question here: 
In most of the cases, json format are exactly same. However, sometime server is responding with "message1" or "message2" or "message3" instead of "message" in the json. In this case, how to update my code so it will be able to parse/decode the json format.